# terminate called after throwing instance of __gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I am currently trying to load textures from files in my class Render and getting this error.

> terminate called after throwing instance of '__gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error'
>
> what(): __gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

I am using Code::Blocks with SFML, and have made sure my project folder isn't read-only

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "dim.h"
#include "render.h"

using namespace std;

sf::RenderWindow window;

int main()
{
    cout << "main" << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));
    Dim world1(64, 64);
    for(int y = world1.y - 1 ; y > 0; y = y - 1)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < world1.x; x++)
        {
            cout << world1.grid.at(y).at(x);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "done"<< endl;

    Render render;
    render.loadTextures();
    for(int i = 0; i < render.fileList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << render.fileList[i] << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**render.h**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

#ifndef RENDER_H_INCLUDED
#define RENDER_H_INCLUDED
class Render
{
public:
    vector<string> fileList; //List of file names
    vector<sf::Texture> textures; //List of textures
    void loadTextures(); //Function to load file names from .txt
    void createWindow(int, int, sf::RenderWindow); //Function to create window
    void setWorld(); //Function to assign sprites' initial positions and textures
};




#endif // RENDER_H_INCLUDED
```

**render.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "render.h"

using namespace std;

void Render::loadTextures()
{
    cout << "loading textures" << endl;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("texturelist.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "texture list file opened" << endl;
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            cout << "reading line" << endl;
            Render::fileList.push_back(line);
            cout << "saved line" << endl;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
    cout << "texture names loaded." << endl;
    Render::textures.resize(Render::fileList.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < Render::fileList.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!Render::textures[i].loadFromFile(Render::fileList[i]))
        {
            cout << "error" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "textures created" << endl;
}

void createWindow(int width, int height, sf::RenderWindow window)
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Game");
    cout << "Window created" << endl;
}
```

full output:

> main
>   creating world
>
> generating layer
>
> splits: 16
>
> generated
>
> generating layer
>
> splits: 16
>
> generated
>
> generating layer
>
> splits: 8
>
> generated
>
> created world
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> 0000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000
>
> 1000000000000000000011111110000000000000000011111110000000000000
>
> 1111100000000000111111111111110000000000111111111111110000000000
>
> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>
> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>
> 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>
> 2111111111111111111111112111111111111111111111111111111111111112
>
> 2211111111111111111122222211111111111111111111112111111111111122
>
> 2221111111112111111122222221111121111111111122222222211111111222
>
> 2222111111122211111222222222222221111111111222222222222111112222
>
> 2222211111222221112222222222222222111111112222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222112222222122222222222222222211111222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222221122222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
>
> 2222222232222222222222222222222222222222222222222222322222222222
>
> 2222222233222222322222222222222222222222222222222222333222223333
>
> 2222222333322233332222222222222222222222222222222223333333333333
>
> 2222222333333333333222222222322222222222222232222223333333333333
>
> 2222223333333333333322223333332222222222222232222233333333333333
>
> 2222223333333333333333333333333222222222222333222233333333333333
>
> 3222233333333333333333333333333333333222223333322333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333332233333332333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
>
> done
>
> loading textures
>
> texture list file opened
>
> reading line
>
> saved line
>
> reading line
>
> saved line
>
> reading line
>
> saved line
>
> texture names loaded.
>
> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>
> '__gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error'
>
> what():  __gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>
> Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>
> Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 3.276 s
>
> Press any key to continue.

Comment: Please share the output that you are getting before the exception comes up.

Comment: added full output. didnt initally want to because of mass of text